# How to change the init system in core-image-minimal yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I would like to create a new target based on `core-image-minimal` and I would like to change the init system with `systemd` over `SysV init`. I would like my change to be permanent (nothing based on local.conf). How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** As Anders pointed out in the comments, i was wrong:

The available init systems are set in the local.conf, but you can indeed change the init system on a per image basis. In your case you want to change it in `core-image-minimal`. This image installs `packagegroup-core-boot` which sets

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager ?= "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts ?= "initscripts"
```

You could create your own `packagegroup-core-boot-systemd` where those variables are set to

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""
```

and install it to your target.

---

<s>The configuration of the init system is a [Distro Feature](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-features-distro). That means it is not in the image recipe, but in the local.conf.</s>

If you don't want to put the configuration in the local.conf, you could create a custom distro configuration with the settings in it. The only thing you have to change in the local.conf is the line

```
# DISTRO = poky
DISTRO = <custom-distro>
```

The reference manual has also a chapter on [creating your own distro](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#creating-your-own-distribution)

Comment: No, the distro configuration is only to decide on which init system should be available. The image decides on which init system to use (of multiple ones are available).

Comment: @Anders yes you are right. I don't have access to my sources at the moment and i can't remember how exactly. I  will happily edit my answer on Monday, or delete this one if you post a correct one.

Comment: I think the best way is to point out the dev-manual : http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#selecting-an-initialization-manager